# Volume of a cone made from circle

Tags: geometry

Circle X has a radius of 15. Points D and F are located on circumference of the circle. Given that angle DXF measures 48°, find the volume of the cone that is formed by aligning the two straight sides.

#### Progress

I tried taking the length of the arc opposite the 48° angle, and used half of that as the radius for the cone. And used 15 as the height, which got me no where near the correct answer.

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem?

Comment: I'm not sure where to start honestly. I tried taking the length of the arc opposite the 48° angle, and used half of that as the radius for the cone. And used 15 as the height, which got me no where near the correct answer...

Comment: What does the angle DXF mean, if X is a circle? Perhaps by X you mean the center of the circle? Also, how is this shape a cone? Looks more like a plane figure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: to find the volume of the cone, you need the base area and the height.

To find the base area, start with the circumference of the "cut-out" circle, use that as the circumference of the base, and then find the area of the circle.

To find the height, use the radius you found in the first half of the problem, and find a way to incorporate Pythagorean Theorem.

Comment: Cut out circle? Do you mean the 48° sector? I don't understand

Comment: The leftover circle after the sector is cut-out. The one that's made into a cone.

Comment: I got the base as 169π and if the slant height of the cone is 15, then the height is 2√14. This brought me to the answer 338π√14/3 which is correct, but why would 15 be used as the slant height?